# 403 Forbidden on site logo image upload

Tags: errors, nonce

When uploading a site logo, I get a 403 Forbidden HTTP error.

Also, the Inspect Element preview shows this page:

[image]

On the site itself, it just says "http error". I tried disabling nonces, no change. I had done `chmod -R 750 <web root dir>` and `chown -R www-data:www-data <web root dir>` too, so I assume permissions are not the issue. (Yes, php-fpm and my web server are running as www-data.)

This is a default install from Wordpress stable version. I have removed my plugins folder too, no change. My web server is NGINX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a good bit of debugging around, I discovered it was that posting over 64 KB(16-bit integer length) of data would cause my modified NGINX to not split up post data in FCGI. After fixing that, it working great.

Comment: so it was indeed nginx not handling requests correctly. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

A few things come in mind

- have you checked nginx access/error log? Depending on your distro, log should be located at `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.
- What role is your current WP user when uploading, does it have required capabilities ?
- Try to change `wp-content` permission to `755`
- Are you having difficulties **only** with images file? If so, might be related to Imagick, try setting GD as [default image editor](https://github.com/getsource/default-to-gd). Add this next filter to default to GD in your `functions.php`. It will return `GD` before `Imagick`. The link provided is a plugin doing just that.

.

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
  return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

Comment: It's the admin user(fresh install), all nginx says is 403 Forbidden. I tried changing the permission, no change. It happens with any upload, regardless of file type.

Comment: hum it's really odd! are you in control of nginx server blocks? if so maybe this would be useful information you could edit your question with, as maybe nginx is doing some kind of wrong proxying of php requests